# Can you share calendars on Microsoft Online Services - Online Exchange

Tags: email

I am in a trial of Microsoft Online Services as our company is looking at Exchange (and Exchange like) email solutions.  MS Online Services is interesting, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do many of the Exchange type tasks in Outlook Web Access.  One of these tasks is sharing a calendar and viewing someone else's shared calendar.

Is this something that can only be done in the Outlook desktop client?  (Something that I cannot use right now because MS Online Services does not support Outlook 2010, only 2007 - would you believe that?)

Answer (score 1):

This is the same thing that I am doing and have found that it can only be done using the Outlook desktop client.

Here is a artcle that I found from Technet:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/onlineservicesexchange/thread/25e2fd87-f272-4327-b154-1193610007ae